# How to group when you already grouped

Tags: sql

I'm lost at a query. I am trying to query the number of festivals based off of tickets sold. IE: The number of festivals hosted that sold between 0 and 250 tickets (Small event), # of festivals hosted that sold between 251 and 500 tickets (Medium event)

What I want is something like this:

| Total Festivals | Festival Size |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | Small Festival |
| 50 | Medium Festival |
| 75 | Large Festival |

I tried something like this, but it never split out what I was looking to achieve:

```
Select count(*) as Total_Festivals, size.festival_type as Festival_Size
from
(Select count(distinct ticket.id) as number_festivals,
case when (Count purchase.id) between '0' and '250' as small_festival
case when (Count purchase.id) between '251' and '500' as medium_festival
case when (Count purchase.id) between '501' and '750' as large_festival
case when (Count purchase.id) > 750 as XL_Festival end as festival_type
from ticket
join purchase on ticket.type = purchase.type) as Size
group by 2
```

Comment: Why are you mixing string literal with integer values?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Why would any proprietary SQL be needed? The question seems solvable (at first-glance) using SQL-92-level functionality.

Comment: @Dai, absolutely, standard ANSI/ISO SQL will be fine. But OP's query is product specific, and it would be great to specify the dbms. (Just to avoid standard/non-standard confusion.)

Comment: mariaDB is what we use.

Comment: With CTEs or sub-queries, you can aggregate the purchase table before joining on the result. The you can have different levels of aggregation at different points in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTEs to build separate datasets and work with them:

```
WITH cte AS(
   SELECT purchase.type, COUNT(*) Countpurchase
   FROM purchase
   GROUP BY  purchase.type   
), cte2 AS (
      SELECT
      cte.Countpurchase,  
      CASE WHEN cte.Countpurchase <= 250 THEN 'Small Festival'
           WHEN cte.Countpurchase <= 500 THEN 'Medium Festival'
           WHEN cte.Countpurchase <= 750 THEN 'Large Festival'
           ELSE 'XL Festival'
      END 'Festival Size',
      FROM ticket
      INNER JOIN cte
      ON cte.type = ticket.type
   )

SELECT SUM(cte2.Countpurchase) 'Total Festivals',
cte2.[Festival Size]
FROM cte2
GROUP BY cte2.[Festival Size]
```